# PHP zip создаёт пустой архив

Tags: php, zip

В чем может быть дело: при создании архива (из одного файла) создаётся пустой zip. Если скормить ему путь к не существующему файлу, архив не создаётся вовсе, что логично. Если путь указан от корня домашней директории `/home/www/citename/files/date/file.ext`, появляется пустой zip. Если указать путь относительно корня сайта `/files/date/file.ext`, в архиве появляется матрешка из директорий, в конце которых таки лежит нужный файл.
В чем моя ошибка?

```
<?php 

$zipArchiveName = $fileName .".zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive(); 
$archive = $tempFolder . "/" . $zipArchiveName; 

if ($zip->open($archive, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) { 
     return; 
} 

if( !$zip->addFile( $filePath ) ){ 
     return; 
} 

$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот способ 100% должен сработать. Если у вас все равно не запишется, проверьте:

1. Права на запись в конечный каталог и чтение исходных.
2. Подключено ли расширение PHP (это не данный случай, поскольку у вас архив все же создается, но у кого-то может быть и с этим проблема).
3. Корректно ли указаны названия файлов и каталогов.

---

```
<?php
$tempFolder = '/home/user/';
$archiveName = 'archive.zip';
$filePath = '/home/user/1.txt';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$archive = $tempFolder . $archiveName;

if (!file_exists($archive)) {
    file_put_contents($archive, null);
}

if ($zip->open($archive, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== true) {
    exit ('Error open');
}

if (!$zip->addFile($filePath, basename($filePath))) {
    exit ('Error adding');
}

$zip->close();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш код сработал. Жаль, но так и не понятно, что не так в моем. Сравнивал все пути посимвольно.

Comment: Проблема не с правами была, значит?

Comment: Абсолютно. Мой продолжает не работать. На права я грешил еще до обращения сюда.

Comment: Ну помимо этого, я только добавил создание архива
`if (!file_exists($archive)) {
    file_put_contents($archive, null);
}`
и `if (!$zip->addFile($filePath, basename($filePath))) {` указание название файла в архиве

Comment: Я первым делом, после успешного теста, этот блок убрал. Но нэт) без него сработало так же.

Comment: Еще возможно, все-таки связано с названием директорий, проверьте слэши, меня это поначалу напрягло) Да, и `return;` - я надеюсь, у вас вызывается внутри функции)

Comment: да, я привел кусок функции. ) вообще сяду и перепроверю посимвольно в скором времени. Самому интересно. Слеши и пути проверил сразу (да и как бы если неверный путь - addFile возвращает false, а там перед return стоял отловщик). В общем пока записано в раздел "мистика")

Comment: Верю, что у вас получится)